# Cannot run php-gpio through apache and using exec() with sudo

Tags: php, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

On my Raspberry Pi Model B-Rev2 running Raspbian 3.10.25 I following the instructions on https://github.com/ronanguilloux/php-gpio to control the pins. But I simple cannot get it to work. According to instructions this should be the command in `triggerMyScript.php`:

```
exec('sudo -t /usr/bin/php ./myGpioScript');
```

But depending on content in `myGpioScript` I get errors in Apache log `error.log` saying stuff like `command not found` and `No such file or directory`.

I have also made additions to /etc/sudoers as instructed.

It works perfectly fine if I run `php triggerMyScript.php` from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending several hours I found the solution. I needed to do the following things beside what the instructions on php-gpio says:

- in `myGpioScript` the first line had to be `#!/usr/bin/php` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env php`
- I had to add `php` after `-t`, like this: `exec('sudo -t php /usr/bin/php ./myGpioScript');` (which makes sense when you think about it, but instructions doesn't say it like that)
- I had to add this to the sudoers file: `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php` - so that www-data can also run php without limitations. Specifying permission for the actual script files was actually not necessary!

File permissions on any of the files are not relevant either, so just leave them low.

Comment: Mainly what you lacked was the part of sudoers file. That's basic to be able to run an script or a command as sudo. If you ever have this problem with python: pi ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/python_gpio_scripts/script.py. I don't recommend you to grant permissions without limitations, you should try to stick to just the scripts you need to run.